# How to refer to a function in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making an html file that basically prints out the coordinates given by the user in a map. Whenever I click the submit button, it returns me an error of "UncaughtReferenceError: NewMap is not defined" i tried using an external javascript and inline javascript but it does not seem to solve the problem. Can you tell me what is wrong with the code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Find My Phone</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#2196F3">
<p style="font-size:150%; text-align:center">This is the extension for the app FindMyPhone. In this site, you can view the coordinates where your phone was traced on a map</p>
Latitude:
<input type="number" step="any" id="Lat"/> <br>
Longitude:
<input type="number" step="any" id="Lng"/> <br>
<button onclick="NewMap()">Submit</button>
<div id="map" style="height:500px;width:500px; color:#9E9E9E">
</div>
<script>
function NewMap() {
   var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map").value;
   var Latitude = document.getElementById("Lat").value;
   var Longitude = document.getElementById("Lng").value;
   var mapOptions = {
    center: document.getElementById("Lat, Lng")
    zoom:15
   }
   var map = new.google.maps.Map (mapCanvas, mapOptions)
  }
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

P.S: Supposing this code works, will it output the map correctly? Please also show me if it is right or wrong.

Comment: Where should I place it then?

Comment: @Marty are you sure about that?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Nah, pretty sure it's because of a syntax error (missing comma and an extra `.`).

Comment: Because onclick will work regardless the fact that it appears before the script... This is pretty much JS 101: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick

Comment: It's a typo. You're missing a comma after `center: document.getElementById("Lat, Lng")`. Your browser is telling you about the problem: Open your web console.

Comment: Thank you it fixed the error1

Comment: You're also not including the Google Maps script.

Comment: There's also a `.` between `new.google`.

Comment: How do I include the google maps script?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: I have a previous API key but not for Google Maps Javascript API it is for Google Maps Geolocation API. Can I also use that key?

Answer (score 1):

1. Include Google Map Library
2. You have missed out a comma after center property.

   var mapOptions = {
   center: document.getElementById("Lat, Lng"),
   zoom:15
   }

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "Google Map Library"?